# Unable to unserialize value - when adding to website magento 2.2

Tags: error, migration, json, unserialize

Migrated fine to 2.2. Now when we open a product and change text for example all works and saves. When trying to assign to another website we get the error

***Unable to unserialize value.***

Log shows: 
***[2017-11-01 22:17:52] main.CRITICAL: Unable to unserialize value. {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Unable to unserialize value. at /home2/staging/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Serialize/Serializer/Json.php:39)"} []***

Tried flushing cache, indexing, etc. Still nothing. Anybody that can help in this?

Comment: I updated our theme (ultimo) to the latest which supports 2.2 as that was not the case with the 2.1 ultimo theme. Since then issue resolved. Not sure if connected but helped.

Comment: try to create module update json data with step with this link:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/ext-best-practices/tutorials/serialized-to-json-data-upgrade.html